# django rest framework https for absolute urls?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The server hosting the api is returning http for absolute urls even though the page was loaded using https, does this have something to do with django rest framework? because there doesn't seem any obvious way to remedy this.

It's the url field in the Meta class that is relevant

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    source = serializers.CharField(source='get_source_url', read_only=True)
    comments_count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    date_added = serializers.CharField(source='humanize_date_added',
                                       read_only=True)
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    user_voted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    favorited = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()    

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        story = News(user=user, **validated_data)
        story.save()
        return story    

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if user.is_active and user == obj.user:
            return True
        return False    

    def get_user_voted(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if user.is_active:
            return obj.user_voted(user)
        return None    

    def get_favorited(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if user.is_active:
            return obj.is_favorite(user)    


    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('id', 'link', 'title', 'text', 'source', 'user',
                  'date_added', 'image', 'comments_count', 'url',
                  'upvotes', 'downvotes', 'user_voted', 'type',
                  'is_owner', 'favorited')
        read_only_fields = ('date_added')
```

i am not sure if it has to do with nginx but i have this in the config

```
proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: rest framework uses django's build_absolute_uri() function to build urls. as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri, this function returns the same scheme, as the one used in the request. so, your webserver probably terminates https connection and Django receives plain http requests. you can confirm this in one of your views by manually calling request.build_absolute_uri(location) function.

Comment: yes, you are correct, setting the `X-Forwarded-Proto` in nginx fixes the issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to make sure nginx forwards the client's request scheme because it'll make a regular http request to Django. You'll need to add the following line to your vhost definition:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but i had to change to `X-Forwarded-Proto`. please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Also don't forget to set up Django's SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER to accept `X-Forwarded-Proto` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Rest Framework reverse() function to build URLs?
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/

It uses incoming request to determine the protocol used.

Comment: i am using the default url in the fields variable in the serializer. it build the url for the item automatically.

Comment: can you update your question with the code you are using?